# Error in my Statistical Quality Control Chart VB code

Tags: vba, excel, charts, controls

I found a macro online that creates a Statistical Quality Control chart online. So I have a .Csv file that looks like an excel sheet. I use the macro, so I have to select the data points. Then I have to select the labels, and then it gets plotted.

My problem is that the Error Bar for UL2 = (upper limit,2*Standard deviation) and LL2=(lower limit, 2* Standard deviation) is not showing up at all. All of the other error bars show up. Such as Average, UL(upper limit) and LL(lower limit) and UL3 and LL3, but not UL2 and LL2.

Also the data points are not along the Average line where they are supposed to be, they are also shifted.

A sample sheet  I used showed up for them, but that was in a regular excel file. The reason I have it in as a .CSV file because I use another macro to extract the raw data and it is pasted in a new .csv file. I'm thinking that is the reason but I am not 100% sure. I was wondering if you guys can help me . I am fairly new to VBA so please bear with me .

Thank you!

Here is the Code that creates the Control Chart :

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetRange(box_message As String) As Range
    Set GetRange = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetRange = Application.InputBox(box_message, "Select Range", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
End Function

Public Function IsNotOk(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean 'TO CHECK IF A GIVEN RANGE IS BLANK
    IsNotOk = True
    On Error GoTo if_error_occured:
    If rng.Rows.Count > 0 And rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then IsNotOk = False
if_error_occured:
    If Err.Number Then IsNotOk = True
End Function

Public Function check_if_numeric(rng As Range) As Boolean
Dim cel As Range
check_if_numeric = True
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(cel.Value)) Then check_if_numeric = False
Next cel
End Function

Sub make_control_chart()
    Dim data_values As Range
    Dim chart_labels As Range
    Dim range_selected_before As Range
    Dim got_label_range As Boolean
    Dim got_value_range As Boolean
    Dim bActivate As Boolean
    Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
    Dim plot_series, MyNewSrs As Series
    Dim series_label As String
    Dim number_of_control_limits As Integer
    Dim standard_deviation As Integer
    Dim data_str As String
    Dim avg_str As String

    On Error GoTo if_error_occured: 'GOTO THE END OF THE PROGRAM

    'GET RANGE FOR DATA VALUES
    bActivate = False   ' True to re-activate the input range
    Set data_values = GetRange("Please select the range containing the DATA POINTS" & Chr(13) & "(press select a single column)")
    If IsNotOk(data_values) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Input Data !"
        End
    ElseIf Not (check_if_numeric(data_values)) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Input Data !"
        End
    End If

    'GET RANGE FOR CHART X-AXIS LABELS
    got_label_range = True   ' True to re-activate the input range
    Set chart_labels = GetRange("Please select the range containing the LABELS" & Chr(13) & "(press ESC if no labels available)")
    If IsNotOk(chart_labels) Then
        got_label_range = False
    End If


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual



    'LETS CREATE THE CHART NOW
    Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=450, Top:=25, Height:=300)
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers


    'REMOVE ALL UNWANTED SERIES FROM CHART, IF ANY
    For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection ' myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        MyNewSrs.Delete
    Next MyNewSrs
    Set MyNewSrs = Nothing


    If got_label_range Then 'IF WE HAVE THE LABEL RANGE
    'ADD NEW SERIES
        Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With MyNewSrs
            .Name = "PLOT"
            .Values = data_values
            .XValues = chart_labels.Value
        End With
    Else
        Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With MyNewSrs
            .Name = "PLOT"
            .Values = data_values
        End With
    End If

    'FORMAT THE PLOT SERIES
    Set plot_series = MyNewSrs
    With MyNewSrs
        .Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerStyle = xlCircle
        .Smooth = False
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .Shadow = False
    End With
    Set MyNewSrs = Nothing





    'CREATE NAMED RANGE FOR THE DATA VALUES, AVERAGE, LOWER AND UPPER CONTROL LIMITS
    data_str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_data_values"
    avg_str = "roundup(average(" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_data_values" & "),2)"

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_data_values", RefersToR1C1:=data_values
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_AVG", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & ""
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL1", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(1*stdev(" & data_str & "),2)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL2", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(2*stdev(" & data_str & "),2)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL3", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(3*stdev(" & data_str & "),2)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL1", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(1*stdev(" & data_str & "),2)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL2", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(2*stdev(" & data_str & "),2)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL3", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(3*stdev(" & data_str & "),2)"



    'ADD THE LINE FOR AVERAGE
    Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With MyNewSrs
        .Name = "AVG = "
        .Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_AVG"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        '.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlNone, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=10000
        '.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlUp, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=20
        .ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=data_values.Rows.Count
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerStyle = xlNone
        .Smooth = False
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .Shadow = False
        With .Border
            .Weight = xlHairline
            .LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'With .ErrorBars.Border
        '    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        '    .ColorIndex = 3
        '    .Weight = xlThin
        'End With
    End With



    Set MyNewSrs = Nothing

    'ADD UPPER AND LOWER CONTROL LIMITS
     For number_of_control_limits = 1 To 3
        For standard_deviation = -1 To 1 Step 2

            Select Case standard_deviation:
                Case -1: series_label = "LCL"
                Case 1: series_label = "UCL"
            End Select

            Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With MyNewSrs
                .Name = series_label & number_of_control_limits & " ="
                .Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_" & series_label & number_of_control_limits
                .ChartType = xlXYScatter
                .ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=data_values.Rows.Count
            End With

            MyNewSrs.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=data_values.Rows.Count

            Select Case number_of_control_limits:
                Case 1:
                            With MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.Border
                                .LineStyle = xlGray25
                                .ColorIndex = 15
                                .Weight = xlHairline
                            End With
                Case 2:
                            With MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.Border
                                .LineStyle = xlGray25
                                .ColorIndex = 57
                                .Weight = xlHairline
                            End With
                Case 3:
                            With MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.Border
                                .LineStyle = xlGray75
                                .ColorIndex = 3
                                .Weight = xlHairline
                            End With
            End Select

            MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlNoCap

            With MyNewSrs
                With .Border
                    .Weight = xlHairline
                    .LineStyle = xlNone
                End With
                .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .MarkerStyle = xlNone
                .Smooth = False
                .MarkerSize = 5
                .Shadow = False
            End With
            Set MyNewSrs = Nothing
        Next standard_deviation
    Next number_of_control_limits

   myChtObj.Chart.ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
        HasLeaderLines:=False, ShowSeriesName:=True, ShowCategoryName:=False, _
        ShowValue:=True, ShowPercentage:=False, ShowBubbleSize:=False, Separator:=" "

    'OFFSET THE LABELS
    For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        With MyNewSrs.Points(1).DataLabel
            .Left = 400
        End With
    Next MyNewSrs


    'LETS FORMAT THE CHART
    With myChtObj
        With .Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
            .MajorTickMark = xlNone
            .MinorTickMark = xlNone
            .TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis
        End With
        With .Chart.Axes(xlValue)
            .MajorTickMark = xlOutside
            .MinorTickMark = xlNone
            .TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis
        End With
        With .Chart.ChartArea.Border
            .Weight = 1
            .LineStyle = 0
        End With
        With .Chart.PlotArea.Border
            .ColorIndex = 1
            .Weight = xlThin
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        With .Chart.PlotArea.Interior
            .ColorIndex = 2
            .PatternColorIndex = 1
            .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With
        With .Chart.ChartArea.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 8
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Background = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With .Chart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Control Chart"
            .ChartTitle.Left = 134
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Observations"
        End With
        With .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels
            .Alignment = xlCenter
            .Offset = 100
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        End With
    End With



    myChtObj.Chart.Legend.Delete
    myChtObj.Chart.PlotArea.Width = 310
    myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
    myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = True


    'DELETE THE LABELS FOR THE ACTUAL DATA SERIES
    plot_series.DataLabels.Delete
    Set plot_series = Nothing

if_error_occured:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    If Err.Number Then z_delete_all_named_range

End Sub


Sub z_delete_all_named_range()
Dim nam As Name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    For Each nam In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    nam.Delete
    Next nam
End Sub
```

[image: This is how it looks like when I plot it]

This is how it looks like when I plot it. The Error bar for UL2 and LL2 arent even there.

Comment: Based on the picture, are they not the dashed black lines? Don't see the UCL1 and LCL1 though. Are UCL1=UCL2 and LCL1=LCL2? Could be rounding issue.

Comment: So sorry for the late response @JJFord3 , and Yeah so from the picture no Error bar is made for UCL2 and LCL2 the text is just overlayed on top of UCL 1 and LCL 1.  and wait so youre saying since th numbers arent being rounded correctly, thats why its messing up ? how is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So LCL1 and LCL2 appear to be the same value after rounding (and UCL1/UCL2 as well). The roundup function above rounds to only two decimal places. To see them differentiated, change the rounding from 2 decimal places to 3 or 4. Recommend changing the average to 3/4 decimal places to match as well, but updated code is below.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL1", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(1*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL2", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(2*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL3", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(3*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL1", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(1*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL2", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(2*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL3", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(3*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
```